# Настройка доступа к сайту извне

Tags: ubuntu, apache, администрирование

Есть Ubuntu, есть Apache, есть сайт, 
есть виртуальный хост с такими настройками:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
        ServerName 192.168.1.2
        DocumentRoot /home/rustam/sites/navigator
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/rustam/sites/navigator>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /home/rustam/sites/navigator/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Есть роутер, на котором прописано то, что на картинке:

[image]

Не могу попасть на сайт через внешний ip.
Может, еще что-то надо прописать?

Answer (score 2):

1. Слишком много записей, пытающихся один порт пробросить на разные адреса :)
2. Сама вебморда роутера не на 80-м порту? Надо их разные порты садить.
3. Ну и в конце поищи кнопку "Применить" или перегрузи коробочку. Не факт, что новые настройки сразу включаются.

Comment: Точно, это решение правильнее. Уберите все адреса, кроме 192.168.1.2

Comment: Штатно, 80 порт веб морды открыт только для внутренних адресов.

Comment: Не могу прописать один ip, та как после перезагрузки роутера всегда меняется внутренний ip

Comment: Внутренние IP обычно выдаются одни и те же. Но Вы можете явно прописать статический адрес интерфейса. https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте настройки iptables в убунту:

```
iptables -nL
```

Так же пропишите в conf файле:

```
ServerAlias ВНЕШНИЙ_IP_АДРЕС
```

сразу после строки

```
ServerName 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Добавил строчку, перезагрузил Apache. не работает

Comment: Что должно быть iptables -nL?

Comment: Выводит modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip_tables': Operation not permitted
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.